# Log of product of 3 matrix exponentials

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm working on a certain problem that involves the following question:

Let $A,B$ be two self-adjoint operators, and define $C=e^{-A}e^{-B}e^{-A}$. Is there a "convenient" way to express $log(C)$? I'm not entirely sure what "convenient" is, looking for anything that could be useful.

I tried two things - the first was using the [Campbell-Baker-Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) formula, but I got very complicated expressions that I do not know how to deal with (since the two operators do not necessarily commute). The second was assuming that one of the operators is diagonal (I simply calculate everything up to a conjugation), but still, I couldn't find a fairly simple way to express what I'm looking for.

Does anyone know of some useful identities/methods that could be useful for this? In the problem I'm working on, $A,B$ depend on two parameters which vary in a certain region, and I want to find a "simple" expression for $log(C)$, so that I can change the parameters and immediately see what happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Interesting problem. As a curiosity, why do you require the operators to have large norms? Normally in BCH one requires the norms to be small in order to have convergence. By the way I don't see another way out except for a nested BCH.

Comment: You are of course correct, a small slip that was corrected :) Yes, so far I haven't been able to find any other way, but hopefully someone might know of a result I am not familiar with

Comment: No problem. What do you need to do with $\log (C)$? For example if what you want is the trace things could simplify considerably.

Comment: Sadly I don't need just the trace, but the operator itself. Just out of curiosity - how would needing only the trace make things much simpler?

Comment: @GSofer: $\operatorname{tr} \log (e^X e^Y)= \operatorname{tr} X + \operatorname{tr}Y.$ (See the end of [this section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Matrix_Lie_group_illustration) of the Wikipedia article you linked to.)

Comment: You could use a Taylor series for $\log$; at least that would give you a single series instead of the double series from two applications of BCH.

Comment: I don't know if this is useful, but you can show that $e^{-A} e^{-B} e^{-A}=e^{-e^{-A} Be^{-A}}e^{-2A}$

Comment: Sorry, meant $e^{-A} e^{-B} e^{-A}=e^{-e^{-A} Be^{A}}e^{-2A}$

Answer (score 1):

We can't say much. We assume that the considered marices are real.

For example, let $R=e^{-A}e^{-B/2}$. Then $C=e^{-A}e^{-B}e^{-A}=RR^T$ is symmetric $>0$.

We consider the $R$'s SVD: $R=U\Sigma V^T$. Then $C=U\Sigma ^2 U^T$ where $U$ is orthogonal. Finally

$\log(C)=2Udiag(\log(\sigma_i)_i)U^T$ where the $(\sigma_i)_i$ are the singular values of $R$.