# product of three Lie matrix exponentials where two are inverse of eachother

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, functional-analysis, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Is there an expression for 
$$\ln\left(e^{-i X}e^{iY}e^{iX}\right)$$
that is better than two nested campbell-baker-hausdorff series? To be specific, my interest is in the case of $Y$ being a general $su(6)$ element and $X$ being a general element of its $su(3)$ subalgebra.

This is a variation on [Log of product of 3 matrix exponentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3500967/log-of-product-of-3-matrix-exponentials), where two of the exponents were totally equal.

Comment: I think:
$$\exp(X)\exp(Y) \exp(- X) =  \exp( e^{\mathrm{ad}(X)}[Y]) = \exp( \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathrm{ad}(X)^n[Y]/n!)$$
is true (replace $X$ with $-iX$ and $Y$ by $iY$ for your formula. Would this forula help you?